# How to predict price for a future day given historical data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

so currently this is the code I have.  Not attached are various graphs that I have made that show the actual stock price from the CSV and then my projections.  I'm wanting to make it where I simply predict tomorrow's stock price given all of this historical data but I'm having a difficult time. The "df.loc[len(df.index)] = ['2022-04-05',0,0,0,0,0,0]" was where I was trying to put the predictions for future days although I am open to other ways.

```
# Machine learning
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# For data manipulation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# To plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')

# To ignore warnings
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")





# method of pandas


df = pd.read_csv('data_files/MSFT.csv')


#add extra row of blank data for future prediction

df.loc[len(df.index)] = ['2022-04-05',0,0,0,0,0,0]
df.loc[len(df.index)] = ['2022-04-06',0,0,0,0,0,0]
df.loc[len(df.index)] = ['2022-04-07',0,0,0,0,0,0]
df.loc[len(df.index)] = ['2022-04-08',0,0,0,0,0,0]

#  Changes The Date column as index columns
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])


# drop The original date column
df = df.drop(['Date'], axis='columns')
print(df)

# Create predictor variables
df['Open-Close'] = df.Open - df.Close
df['High-Low'] = df.High - df.Low

# Store all predictor variables in a variable X
X = df[['Open-Close', 'High-Low']]
X.head()

# Target variables
y = np.where(df['Close'].shift(-1) > df['Close'], 1, 0)
print(y)

split_percentage = 0.8
split = int(split_percentage*len(df))

# Train data set
X_train = X[:split]
y_train = y[:split]

# Test data set
X_test = X[split:]
y_test = y[split:]

# Support vector classifier
cls = SVC().fit(X_train, y_train)


df['Predicted_Signal'] = cls.predict(X)


# Calculate daily returns
df['Return'] = df.Close.pct_change()


# Calculate strategy returns
df['Strategy_Return'] = df.Return * df.Predicted_Signal.shift(1)


# Calculate Cumulutive returns
df['Cum_Ret'] = df['Return'].cumsum()


# Plot Strategy Cumulative returns
df['Cum_Strategy'] = df['Strategy_Return'].cumsum()
```

Comment: You can try `df.append()` instead. See doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Comment: @le_camerone `append` is getting deprecated

Comment: `pd.concat()` then?